# Accessing variables and methods from another file

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, object

In this case, How do I access the variable and method declared in a file from another file?

File one

```
jQuery(function(t) {

    var myVar = 'myValue',

    e = function(t) {
        console.log('myLog');
    }

});
```

File two

```
jQuery(function($){
    // ????
});
```

Comment: "File one" doesn't expose anything to *be* used.  Except maybe the scope of the `e` variable.  Are you not able to use that?  What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't. It has nothing to do with files (JavaScript largely doesn't care about files unless they're ES2015+ modules), it has to do with the fact that both `myVar` and `e` are **entirely private** to the anonymous function you're passing into `jQuery` in the first code block. Even other code outside that function in the same file would be unable to access them.

You'd have to change the first file to make that information accessible outside that function. You could do that by making them globals (blech), or by having a *single* global you use for all of your things like this with an object with properties for these things (slightly less "blech" :-) ), or by using something like Webpack and true modules.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on how you setup your scripts. For instance:

```
<script src="fileOne.js"></script>
<script src="fileTwo.js"></script>
```

Then you will be able to do the following:

File One:
- Declare variable x

File Two:
 - Access variable x

I recommend taking a look at this, it'll help with understanding variable scope (however this doesn't cover ES6's let): https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp